# How to import data from website into SAP WEBI

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-scraping, webi

Do you guys know what is the best method to import data from any website to put in webi report?

I just want to capture the value that displayed in the web, like web scraping/crawl.

As example, getting the oil price from https://www.oil-price.net/:

[image]

Using Excel/powerBI is very easy to do this as it have power query features but I didn't find how to do this in WEBI.

FYI, the website is just an example. just want to show that I want to take the value that similar like that oil price website.

OR is it that we need to use another program to capture the data and store in SQL database and create new universe?

Really appreciate if you can share link or references of how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: `Using Excel is very easy to do this` and how you do web-scraping in Excel?

Comment: in excel its not really web scraping, the power query just detect any table that exist in the web page (like above picture). can look in excel data tab > get data > other sources > web